# Swift - Convert nested JSON to dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

How do I get a dictionary for all levels of nested json data?

JSON data:

```
{"places":[
    {"name":"東京","date":"2005/03/02","transport":"新幹線"},
    {"name":"北海道","date":"2006/04/06","transport":"飛行機"}
    ],
 "no_of_person":"4",
 "package_name":"日本最高"
}
```

My code:

```
let response: String = "{\"places\":[{\"name\":\"東京\",\"date\":\"2005/03/02\",\"transport\":\"新幹線\"},{\"name\":\"北海道\",\"date\":\"2006/04/06\",\"transport\":\"飛行機\"}],\"no_of_person\":\"4\",\"package_name\":\"日本最高\"}"
    
let jsonObj = response.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let items = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonObj, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    print(items)    
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

My terminal output:

```
["package_name": 日本最高, "places": <__NSArrayI 0x280fde800>(
{
    date = "2005/03/02";
    name = "\U6771\U4eac";
    transport = "\U65b0\U5e79\U7dda";
},
{
    date = "2006/04/06";
    name = "\U5317\U6d77\U9053";
    transport = "\U98db\U884c\U6a5f";
}
)
, "no_of_person": 4]
```

As shown in the terminal output above,

1. How do I get "places" as a Dictionary instead of an Array?
2. Also how can I keep the Japanese text as it is, like the one in the
   "package_name"?

**EDIT:**
Correction: How do I get "places" as an array of Dictionaries?

Comment: Please, don't use `JSONSerialization`, use `JSONDecoder`. Dictionary is almost always the wrong structure to represent your data.

Comment: Your japanese text has not changed. That's only how the console displays it.

Comment: places is an array in the json so it is an array after conversion. If you want it a dictionary you must create your own decoder . You will have to decide what to use as key for the dictionary

Comment: What would the value of your "places" dictionary be? In the JSON, it's an array. What value would you like instead for this example?

Comment: @Sulthan It shows the unicode on the phone too. I'd like to keep the Japanese text like the "package_name".

Comment: @RobNapier I'd like it to be an array of Dictionaries,`[["name":"東京","date":"2005/03/02","transport":"新幹線"],["name":"北海道","date":"2006/04/06","transport":"飛行機"] `

Comment: It's an array of dictionaries now. It's exactly what you're describing. I think the output of `print` is confusing you. (It's also exactly the same string. You're just seeing how `print` deals with an NSDictionary and what UTF-8 looks like when printed in through an NSDictionary. You should generally avoid JSONSerialization, but even so, it's exactly what you're describing.)

Comment: @RobNapier Well noted. Like mentioned by Sulthan, I'd better use JSONDecoder.

Comment: FYI: `__NSArrayI`, that means NSArrayImmutable, ie a `NSArray`, easily bridged with a Swift array. That's how are printed `NSArray`. And it's appearing in the log because by default os JSONSerialization, it will trtansform into NSArray/NSDictionary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you if you would like to use jsondecoder.

```
struct SampleData: Codable {
    let places: [Place]
    let no_of_person: String
    let package_name: String
}

struct Place: Codable {
    let name: String
    let date: String
    let transport: String
}

do {
    var dataDecoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(SampleData.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print("uppsss there is something wrong in decoding: \(error)")
}
```